# python 3 and the file object

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

I am looking at using setup.py to automatically generate python 3 code from python 2 sources using the 'use_2to3' attribute. My setup.py script includes the following statement:

```
VERSION = None
with file('version','rt') as FF:
    VERSION = FF.read().lstrip().rstrip()
print("VERSION %s" % (VERSION) )
```

When I type 'python3 setup.py build' I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    with file('version','rt') as FF:
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

which I understand is correct as the file object no longer exists and I should change it to 'open()'.

The concern is that the '2to3' utility does *not* detect this and leaves the code untouched.
I unfortunately use this idiom throughout my code.

Is this a bug in '2to3' ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `open` instead of the `file`.

It was tempting to use the `file()` instead of the `open()` in Python 2.x -- especially for those with OO background. The `file()` call resembled calling a constructor for creation of a file object. However, it was always recommended to use `open()` function instead. This may be the reason why `2to3` does not solve the case.

In Python 3, the `file` is unknown. The file objects are of the `_io.TextIOWrapper` class:

```
>>> f = open('a.txt', 'w')
>>> type(f)
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
>>> f.__class__.__name__
'TextIOWrapper'
```